# PHP Countdown Timer action

Tags: javascript, php, timer, countdown

Hi all apologies if this is an easy solution, I am creating an test application and require that a timer is started when the user clicks on the test. I am however completely confused how to implement a counter for the application - and how to trigger an action when the timer has reached 0.

I have found implementations of JS timers/countdowns:

[PHP Timer wait 30 seconds then run a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942610/php-timer-wait-30-seconds-then-run-a-command)

[PHP when countdown runs out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184156/php-when-countdown-runs-out)

and a php timer:

[Start and stop a timer PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310487/start-and-stop-a-timer-php)

I was hoping that someone could help me with an example of a PHP timer that triggers an action when it has reached 0 for example - redirecting to another page.

Many thanks in advance - please have patience, I am a total beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery:

```
function runTimer(seconds, yourUrl) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.get(yourUrl);
  }, seconds * 1000;
}
```

run it:

```
runTimer(5, 'http://example.com/action.php');
```

But it won't be possible to redirect to other page using ajax request.

For redirecting use:

```
function runTimerRedirect(seconds, yourUrl) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = yourUrl
  }, seconds * 1000;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much - sorry to be a pain but is there a PHP solution or is this all strictly client side